# 5x5 Stronglift squats and hip replacement

Tags: weightlifting

Please can someone help me.  I have been looking into the 5x5 stronglifts, and I am keen to get started as I need to get in shape, and I like the look of the results.  I have difficulty doing squats because I was born with half dislocated hip joints.  I have had surgeries to deepen the sockets, and recently found out that I need a hip replacement because the top of my bone 'has died and worn away'.  I can do a few easy ones, but definitely struggle with lunges.  Should i just start with light squats and build up, or should I just avoid these altogether?  I am worried about using heavy weights with squats in case my hip dislocates.  They already click and pop.  Is there anything else I can do to get the same results without doing squats?  I know the squats are an important part of the routine, but want the results and the strength.  Thanks for any advice.

Comment: This is a health question you should discuss with your surgeon (or another medical professional). We can't really tell how your situation is, so it would basically come down to wild guessing which won't help anyone.

Comment: The squats are definitely a key part of stronglifts, and I suspect that deadlifts might give you similar issues. Definitely discuss what you can do without further damage with your doc.

Comment: Your physical therapist should be able to give you a good strengthening program to get you ready for your hip replacement and strengthen without compromising your hips.